# Can't get Pixel Data from DICOM using GDCM

Tags: visual-c++, dicom, gdcm

I need some help with [GDCM](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/).

I've been trying to get the Pixel Data from DICOM file for a few days. There are lot's of ways how to do it... I decided to use GDCM.
I download their libraries and try to get pixel data like this:

```
#include "gdcmFileHelper.h"
#include "gdcmFile.h"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   gdcm::File *f1 = new gdcm::File();
   f1->SetFileName( 'test.dcm' );
   f1->Load();   
   gdcm::FileHelper *fh = gdcm::FileHelper::New(f1);
   unsigned int *imageData = fh->GetImageDataRaw();
   unsigned int imageDatasize = fh->GGetImageDataRawSize();
   return 0;
}
```

But, I have no `gdcmFileHelper.h` in their list of headers and lib's ...
So I've tried like this:

```
#include "gdcmImageReader.h"
#include "gdcmImage.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gdcm::ImageReader reader;
  reader.SetFileName( filename );
  const gdcm::Image &image = reader.GetImage();
  return 0;
}
```

How can i get pixel data in this way ? Or .. where can i get `gdcmFileHelper.h`...

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [image.GetBuffer()](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classgdcm_1_1Bitmap.html#a25c8f12afa96fce5f19fcc0aa2c46a26), see for example the PIL <-> GDCM binding:

[ConvertPIL.py](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/ConvertPIL_8py-example.html)

You first example will not work, it uses GDCM 1.x, which has been abandoned AFAIK.